# Angular 6 - get file from disk

Tags: angular

I have some files on my disc which I would like to download. Is it possible to do in a similar way which I want to do it? I attach example but I didn't work.

```
  ngOnInit() {
  this.fetchPlugin()
    }

    fetchPlugin(){
      console.log("Fetching...")
      forkJoin(
        this.httpClient.get('C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\file.js', {responseType: "blob"}),
        this.httpClient.get('C:\\Users\\xxx\\file2.js', {responseType: "blob"}),
        this.httpClient.get('C:\\Users\\xxx\\file3.js', {responseType: "blob"})
      ).subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response)

      });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: You can't!

The reason is, those Angular codes are simply Javascript codes which are executed on the client computer. For many reasons, the Javascript programming language is unable to, let's say, is not allowed to access the file system of the client computer.

Accessing the file system using Javascript is only possible with NodeJS - a javascript framework which allows you programming on the server-side using Javascript programming language.

Answer (score 1):

you can use nodejs or any backend language you are using to respond the file you require. In expressjs u can even use `res.download('file_path',callback())`, Angular is used for client side manipulation.

Comment: Ok, which backend language/framework do you recommend? I need only simple REST service with one endpoint so I would like to have really light and simplify server. Also are they other opportunities for javascript other than express.js ?

Comment: ExpressJS is the most popular and lightweight web framework of NodeJS, my friend